# ftp_login(): Please reconnect using TLS security mechanisms

Tags: php, ssl, ftp

I receive this error with my connection FTP:

> ftp_login(): Please reconnect using TLS security mechanisms

This is the code:

```
$ftp_server="xxxx";
$ftp_username="xxxx";
$ftp_password="xxxx";
$ftp_connessione = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
$login = ftp_login($ftp_connessione, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
if(!$ftp_connessione || !$login){ 
    echo "Connessione fallita";
} else {
```

I learn the documentation of FTP but I not found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the FTP server requires a TLS/SSL encryption, you need to use [`ftp_ssl_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) instead of `ftp_connect`:

```
$ftp_connessione = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);
```